# Adding TurnOffFetchThrottling registry key doesn't have any effect

Tags: registry, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, registrykey

I have tried with adding **TurnOffFetchThrottling** registry key on CRM machines in order to avoid limitation in retrieving records via API call (paging). I followed instructions from [this link](http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/server-tips/turn-off-microsoft-crm-2011-5000-limit-on-data-retrieval-via-sdk/). Here is also [MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911510).

In my case this fix doesn't work. Here is list of installed CRM updates:
[image]

This whould extreamly speed up execution of lots of workflows I have in system. Now there is tons of warnings in event viewer like this one:
[image]

Any idea what could be problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue here and I'm not sute if we are supposed to fill the reg entry with the result ammount we desire.

MS says: Step 6 lets you retrieve the number of records specified in the Count attribute of your fetch statement.

I understand that if I add that entry it will allow me to get the ammount result I specify in "int fetchCount = X;". But I was thinking that if I want like, 30k results I would have to fill 30k on the reg entry.

Answer (score 0):

This registry key was added to one of our environment.  One unintended result was an error when trying to assign role based forms.  The pop-up displayed the message 'Invalid Argument'.  The download log button was not available.

There was also a CrmException in the event log: 'Value for this parameter must be equal or greater than zero' (Event Code 3005).

This was in CRM 2011 (on premise of course).